# laravel dusk is giving the same CURL error whenever I try to run it

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-dusk

Whenever I try running `php artisan dusk`, I always get this error:

```
Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"browserName":"chrome","goog:chromeOptions":{"binary":"","args":["--disable-gpu","--headless","--window-size=1920,1080","platform:mac","--no-sandbox"]}}]},"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","chromeOptions":{"binary":"","args":["--disable-gpu","--headless","--window-size=1920,1080","platform:mac","--no-sandbox"]}}}

Operation timed out after 10004 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

I have tried all the solutions out there concerning similar problems but none of theme have worked.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Check if the dusk driver matches your current chrome version. E.g. if you have chrome 84 then run `php artisan dusk:chrome-driver 84`

Comment: How can I check my chrome version?

Comment: Open chrome, clock on the top right ⋮ icon, then  Help > About google chrome . in linux you can also use`google-chrome --version`

Answer (score 4):

Run:

```
php artisan dusk:chrome-driver --detect
```